# implement returnurl in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to implement returnurl in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear so I can only be guessing. Personally I pass `returnUrl` as parameter to actions that need to redirect:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string returnUrl)
{
    // TODO: some processing ...

    // TODO: sanitize the url ensuring that it belongs to the same domain
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

and then I build HTML forms to invoke the action and pass the return url:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller"))
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We did something like this in one of our projects.

In your controller, add a parameter for the returnUrl then in your method just redirect to it.

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(int id, string returnUrl)
{
    //do some stuff

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        //return whatever
    }
}
```